# How to get the names of objects

Tags: ruby

I want to store the names of instances in an array by calling a class method.

When I try, it returns the whole instance. When I put `object_id`, it returns the integer identifier of my object. I want the name of the instances in an array, and later with that array, I want to sort the objects by their `last_name`.

I tried this:

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :years, :height, :work, :last_name
    @@people=[]
    def initialize(name)
        @name=name
        @@people << self #WHAT TO TYPE HERE???
    end

    def <=> (other_person)  # to compare two people, use last names
      self.last_name <=> other_person.last_name
    end

    def self.number_of_instances
        return @@people
    end

end                
mike=Person.new("michael")
mike.years=45
mike.height=141
mike.work="singer"
mike.last_name="zux"

bob=Person.new("boby")
bob.years=29
bob.height=150
bob.work="soldier"
bob.last_name="awax"

steven=Person.new("stephan")
steven.years=24
steven.height=179
steven.work="painter"
steven.last_name="sigal"

elena=Person.new("eli")
elena.years=20
elena.height=171
elena.work="menager"
elena.last_name="betany"
a= Person.number_of_instances

sorted_names= a.sort!{|first,second| first<=>second }
p sorted_names
```

The expected output should be sorted by the alphabetical order of their `last_name`:

```
[bob, elena, steven, mike]
```

Is there a way to store the names that I assigned to the whole objects like `bob`, `elena`, `steven`, `mike`?

Comment: what would to be expected output, you could include the expected out put as well.

Comment: Judging from your code, you should store `last_name` in that class variable (instead of `object_id`)

Comment: @Rajagopalan i include expected output into my code now you can see

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i want this way, i want to store object names and then to do some operations on that objects

Comment: @BobanJankovic: huh? If you store names, you have stored names, not objects. In order to get the objects, you need a dictionary/repository of some kind that will fetch you an object by its name. Is it not easier to store objects themselves?

Comment: is there a way to store names that i assigned do whole objects like bob,elena,steven,mike and that names is going to point on object themselves in array

Comment: I updated an answer, I believe that would answer your question.

Comment: You are asking to store the variable’s name.  More than one variable name can point to the same object.  I would strongly reconsider why you feel you should do it this way.

Comment: FYI, an English sentence ends with a period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :last_name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @last_name = ""
  end
end

class Team
  attr_accessor :team
  def initialize
    @team = []
  end

  def <<(person)
    team.push(person)
  end

  def people_by_last_name

    team.sort_by { |person| person.last_name }.map(&:name)
  end
end
team = Team.new
person = Person.new("Mark")
person.last_name = "Davids"
team << person

person = Person.new("John")
person.last_name = "Stephenson"
team << person

puts team.people_by_last_name
```

Comment: thats property name i want location where is stored my object

Comment: If you want to operate on a collection of people, I might suggest that you need a new class, say Team.

I'll add example code.

Comment: Added the code let me know if it makes sense. I know it's a different approach then what you were trying to take, but it is simpler to have two classes to share the responsibilities you require, and is a little less brittle than relying on a class variable

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The return of people_by_last_name in the code above matches what you describe as your expected output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the name in the array, then you just put the name in the array:

```
@@people << name
```

Comment: its just a parametar name i dont want that i want store names that i assigned do whole objects like bob,elena,steven,mike

Comment: Boban, I didn't notice Jörg's answer when I posted. But his answer is correct.

Comment: @BobanJankovic: Then what you want cannot be done. Ruby is an object-oriented language, you can only store, return, and pass objects. Variables aren't objects in Ruby, therefore, you cannot store, return or pass them. You can only assign to them and dereference them, those are the only two operations allowed on variables.